# Not able to create and push the branch content into GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, repository, push, branch

I've created a branch on my local repository. First, I checked out to my created branch from master. And then I'm trying to push the branch to my main repository created in GitHub with - `git push origin <branch- name>`

But when I run that above command in my Linux console system, it's getting executed but it's not going further at all. It's always getting stuck in the console at -

```
linux@lenovo:~/LocalGitHubRepo$ git push origin <branch-name>
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 880 bytes | 880.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

It's not showing successful message of completion. When I refresh page in GitHub repository I'm not able to see created local `<branch-name>` in the repository. Only `master` branch is displaying the GitHub.

Comment: After waiting for few mins, I got this error in the console ->                                   `Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: Can you check if you have access to push code to the github repo?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "access to push code" here in github repo ?

Comment: Actually I was able to push everything (including branch and master ) to one of my last created repo. But I created one more new, did `git init` , `git remote add origin "(SSH connection of repo)"` etc.. ... Then when I created new branch and try to push it, not happening !!

Comment: In you github , are you able to see the origin branch of your repo?

Comment: @Arihant .... Yes I can see those earlier created origin branches

Comment: This completely seemed to be network issue with my system and github repo. This got solved itself after reconnected to the network properly and running the `git push origin (branch-name)` again. This time I could see branch name in main repo in github . This is RESOLVED now .